# Is it possible to catch a custom oracle sql trigger exception in Spring and pass it on to React?

Tags: sql, reactjs, oracle, spring-boot, exception

I'm using a namedparameterjdbctemplate to have my crud in an oracle db. I have a trigger which sometimes throws a custom exception during update or delete. Is it possible to extract its message in my Spring Boot backend and pass it on to a React front? I tried try and catch in dao and it said sqlexceptions aren't thrown there

```
@Override
    public void delete(Integer id) {
        SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("ID_SETTINGS", id);
            namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(DELETE_SQL, parameters);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to catch the wrong exception, should be a RuntimeException and you are catching a checked Exception.

If you want to return errors/stacktraces it's best to have a global exception handler controller for uncaught exceptions and you can return responses accordingly. Typically you don't want to return SQL exceptions vanilla because this could lead to security issues, although you might return stack-traces in your dev environment, but hide them in prod. Best practice though is to not return exceptions to the front-end but instead log them, and return user-friendly error messages.